# JSON_ENCODE for two columns with same name in php

Tags: php, mysql

my problem is i want to JSON_ENCODE the result of inner join query and the two columns i want to select **have the same name** so, the JSON object override one of them and carry only data for one column cause they have the same name,,this is my code till now.

```
 $query = "select faculty.NAME,sector.NAME from faculty inner join sector
        on faculty.SECTOR_ID=sector.ID";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$rows[] = $r;
 }
 echo json_encode($rows);
```

how to do this without change the column name in the DataBase...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the output of your query:

```
select faculty.NAME AS facultyName,sector.NAME AS sectorName from faculty inner join sector
    on faculty.SECTOR_ID=sector.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`as`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html):

```
select faculty.NAME as faculty_name, sector.NAME as sector_name from faculty inner join sector
    on faculty.SECTOR_ID=sector.ID
```

This will change your json values to something like:

```
{"faculty_name": "first", "sector_name": "second"}
```

so you will need to update your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ALIAS` In your query so you will have different names for your columns

```
select faculty.NAME as faculty_name ,sector.NAME as sector_name
```